# Android target sdk 33, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO not working

Tags: android

I have requested below two permissions in app,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO " />
```

Then I allow the permissions, and verify from 'App permissions'

[image]

But, the app still dont have the READ_MEDIA_VIDEO  permission, e.g the below code return false. And the app cannot access/read the videos from device.

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        context!!,
        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

Comment: I haven't begun any Android 13 projects, so I can't provide any guidance. However, under the subheading **System Photo Picker**: "Apps can use the new photo picker APIs in Android 13 to prompt the user to pick which photos or videos to share with the app, without that app needing permission to view all media files." https://blog.esper.io/android-13-deep-dive/#system_photo_picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app only needs to access images, photos, and videos, consider using the **[photo picker](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/features/photopicker)** instead of declaring the READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_MEDIA_VIDEO permissions.

More details available [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13)

According to Google storage [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage.). It seems that for non-media files no permission is needed.

Comment: i already implmented my own photo/video picker, still want to request the permission.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually i made a silly mistake, there is a space in the permission declaration...